# jQuery click events not firing within AngularJS templates

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This may be a bit of strange case where nobody has ever experienced this before, but I'm posting this on the off-chance that somebody knows something I don't.

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 and AngularJS.

If I have an anchor in `index.html` like so:

```
# index.html
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() { console.log("click"); });
});
</script>
```

Then it works, and when I click it, it outputs 'click'. But when I put that inside a template that I include with the `ng-include` attribute, the jQuery all of a sudden doesn't fire. If I place the script inside the template with the anchor though, it DOES fire.

```
# index.html
<div ng-include="'path/to/template.html'"></div>

# template.html
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() { console.log("click"); });
});
</script>
```

This is also the case with using directives which use templates. It's bizarre and causing me a lot of hassle with some drop down menus.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Probably something to do with the DOM not being ready at time of binding, BUT, you should put all dom manipulation into directives!!!!!

Comment: can you put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: This is a simplified case, in actuality it's a javascript file that is called in the index.html that wants to handle the navigation menu.

Comment: is there any angular controller ?

Comment: You really should use a directive for this.

Comment: I was, I just simplified my example. It was a directive that wasn't firing js events.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Since your `clickme` probably isn't available on DOM ready - rather it is pushed into the DOM by Angular when it loads `template.html` - you need to use jQuery's event delegation instead of using `.click`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function() {
  console.log("click");
});
```

This will ensure jQuery binds onto the document, then monitors for any click events on elements with the `clickme` class.

Comment: This works, thanks. Looks like the bootstrap theme I'm using wasn't designed for Angular. I reckon I can upgrade it with this though. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. The `$(document)` selector is just an example, it's better if you bind onto a parent element of `.clickme` - obviously one that isn't also generated by Angular :)

Comment: Thanks, I bound it to the smallest parent that was inside index.html, all working now. Marked as answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Works partially for me but the delegate event is not firing in first click, could you help me on this?

Comment: Not working for me:

`$(".bordered-button-red .show-guide-button").on("click", function () {
        alert("Clicked!");
});`