# jQueryUI events not working with Angularjs,navigates on click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am working on an angularjs based app where I have some controls of jQueryUI. My page has a navigation panel which collapsible/expandable.on click it expands and show menu and slides back on click again(toggle) but when I do this with angular page my url redirects to otherwise(default page).If I use event.stoppropagation my jQuery controll stops working and toggle functionality doesn't work.
I tried HTML mode as well but couldn't succeed . below is my app.js (for routing) and HTML where  MENU invokes toggling of menu item. any idea would be great help.

```
$routeProvider
 .when('/', {templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html', controller:'loginCtrl'})
  .when('/overview', {templateUrl: 'app/views/overviewDashboard.html', controller:'overviewDashboardCtrl'})
  .when('/changepassword', {templateUrl: 'app/views/changePassword.html', controller:'changePasswordCtrl'}) 
  .when('/discoverysettings', {templateUrl: 'app/views/discoverySettings.html', controller:'discoveryCtrl'}) 
  .when('/managedObject', {templateUrl: 'app/views/managedObject.html',controller:'managedObjectCtrl'}) 

  .when('/search', {templateUrl: 'app/views/search.html'}) 
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/overview' });
```

HTML is

```
                <aside class="left clear side-menu expanded">
            <a href="#" target="_self" class="menu-controller" >MENU</a>

            <nav role="navigation" class="side-nav">
            <ng:include src="'app/views/sidebar.html'"></ng:include>

            </nav><!-- end side-nav -->
        </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I got my answer at [jQuery click events not firing within AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876537/jquery-click-events-not-firing-within-angularjs-templates).

replacing jQuery event in below format solved the problem .

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function() {
  console.log("click");
});
```

and the html changes

```
<a href="#" target="_self" class="menu-controller">MENU</a>
```