# JQuery selector not working on Angular ng-include

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I was testing ng-include in an angular application with JQuery, and I could not fire an event from JQuery on HTML content loaded from **ng-include**.

In this example, the page has two panels with two click events, the painel1 that is on index.html page and the painel2 that is on contentPanel.html that is being included via ng-include, althought the click event on panel2 from contentPanel.html is not working.

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body" id="painel1">
                {{panel1Text}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="'app/shared/contentPanel.html'"></div>
</div>


<script src="./assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function($scope){
    $scope.panel1Text = 'Panel 1, click here!';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#painel1').on('click', function(){
        alert('Você clicou em um painel!');
    });

    $('#painel2').on('click', function(){
        alert('Você clicou em um painel!');
    });
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the file contentPanel.html that I am including on ng-include:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body" id="painel2">
            Panel 2, click here!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach might help, perhaps you can bind jQuery click to `#painel2` instead of `.clickme` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876537/jquery-click-events-not-firing-within-angularjs-templates

Comment: The `jQuery on` might being executed before `ng-include` loads the template. Why not just use `ng-click`?

Comment: @CastroRoy That was the right thing to do I guess, but I have an JQuery layout that I'm using with angular, and it would be not practical change all JQuery events to angular, and if it have some updates on that layout, I'll have to change my code too.

Comment: @AndyRaddatz That worked! If you want to answer the question so I can mark as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a jQuery click event to the document itself and then the DOM creation cycle with `ng-include` won't break the binding:

```
$(document).on("click", "#painel2", function() {
    alert('Você clicou em um painel!');
});
```

I got the answer from here: [jQuery click events not firing within AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876537/jquery-click-events-not-firing-within-angularjs-templates)

Answer (score 0):

One way is use from `ng-controller='HomeController'` in your file(`contentPanel.html`) and write your controller name in a contentPanel.html page then your HTML file can read controller